# Error launching Huxley/Selenium record session

Tags: python, selenium

I'm having a problem when attempting to start a fresh record with Huxley. The exception error returned is below:

```
------------------------------------
Running Huxley file: huxtestfile.txt
------------------------------------
[login] Running test: login
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\threading.py", line 761, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Test\projects\net10-test\net10-test\lib\site-        packages\huxley\threadpool.py", line 32, in thread
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Test\projects\net10-test\net10-test\lib\site-packages\huxley\cmdline.py", line 69, in run_test
    screensize=screensize
  File "C:\Users\Test\projects\net10-test\net10-test\lib\site-packages\huxley\main.py", line 83, in main
    d = webdriver.Remote(remote, CAPABILITIES[browser])
  File "C:\Users\Test\projects\net10-test\net10-test\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Test\projects\net10-test\net10-test\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 115, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "C:\Users\Test\projects\net10-test\net10-test\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 166, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Test\projects\net10-test\net10-test\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: None ; Stacktrace:
```

I have installed Huxley into a python virtualenv and ensured that the selenium server is running before attempting to start the record. My huxley file is a very basic:

```
[login]
url=http://2.2.2.2/login.html
```

I've confirmed my web application is accessible from Firefox (using the above URL) and I can navigate to `127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub` successfully.

Any pointers/suggestions would be appreciated. If I've missed any essential details let me know and I'll update the original post.

Thx.

UPDATE:

Further investigation with Fiddler has revealed that the POST request contains a NULL value for the sessionID. The resulting NullPointerException error appears to be the root cause of my Unknown Error.

```
{"sessionId":null,"status":13,"value":    {"message":null,"localizedMessage":null,"suppressed":    [],"cause":null,"class":"java.lang.NullPointerException","hCode":3963113,"stackTrace":    [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,    null,null,null,null,null,null]},"state":"unhandled     error","class":"org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response","hCode":2501105}
```

I am still trying to resolve the problem, I will update again with my results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was being caused by an incompatibility with Selenium 2.35 and Firefox 30.0 - updating Selenium to the latest version was required; however Huxley is initially configured to only operate with 2.35 as per this issue (https://github.com/facebook/huxley/issues/42)

Updating the requires.txt as follows:

```
selenium>=2.35.0
plac==0.9.1
Pillow==2.2.1
jsonpickle==0.4.0
```

Allows huxley to run with the updated Selenium version.